# Inserts are out of order even with auto-incrementing primary key

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with 3 columns: `id` (auto-incrementing PK), `product_id`, `project_id`.

`product_id` and `project_id` are foreign keys. There is also a unique key for those 2 columns.

I'm finding that when I do a simple "SELECT * FROM myTable", the results are not primarily being ordered by the `id` column. They appear to first be ordered by `id` but then also the other 2 columns. So, I insert (5, 10) into the table and then (5, 6), then select them, I get:

id | product_id | project_id

2 | 5 | 6

1 | 5 | 10

How does this happen?

Comment: You can't expect the results of a query to be returned in the same order of insertion. If you want the results ordered you should modify the query to reflect it (order by).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't explicitly request an order with `ORDER BY`, MySQL displays the results in the order it reads them from an index.

I would infer that MySQL is using your UNIQUE index to read these rows, so they're read from that index in order by product_id first, then by project_id.

By analogy, if you read names from the telephone book, you read them in order by last name and then by first name. That's the order they're stored, regardless of which phone number was assigned first.

The id column is the primary key, which is implicitly appended to every non-primary index.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, databases do not have a "default" order, so if you do not specify an implicit order, you can not make any assumptions on the final order of the results. If you need to retrieve the records in any certain order, you should append " ORDER BY " at the end of your query. 
Please, note that the exact same query, without an order by clause, can produce results in very different order.

Answer (score 0):

Do not depend on order when ORDER BY is missing.

The ORDER BY keyword sorts the records in ascending order by default. To sort the records in a descending order, you can use the DESC keyword.

So there's even no guarantee that two queries which look the same will return results in the same order: if you don't specify it, you cannot rely on it.